# multi call of SP.SOD.executeFunc

Tags: sharepoint-server, jsom

the problem is very clear that the call of SP.ClientContext and  sp.js isnot done yet.
Actually, In my master page there is the code to get those two :

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getData);
```

and it works very well.

and in another page , i need to get other data using JSOM , so i added the same call , and its always the error :

> error SP.ClientContext   is undefined

so i tried :

```
RegisterSodDep('RenderData', 'sp.js');
    RegisterSodDep('RenderData', 'SP.ClientContext');
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.ClientContext', null,GetListOfSitesForCurrentUser);
```

and even :

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetListOfSitesForCurrentUser, "sp.js")
```

I can see the problem is that "sp.js" isn't get yet, but how can I resolve this, especialy that the call is done in master page for another function, and i can touch this function never .

Comment: Does you page has SharePoint master page? If not then you will have to reference these files in your code/html..

Comment: yes it has a master page ; and its reefrenced, the probleme that the call is done already on the master page

Comment: efer this link. May be this will help you. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/df8d2f16-0af9-48b5-9892-e4b9bcd6dd09/javascript-runtime-error-clientcontext-is-undefined?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had [similar issues](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240948/another-load-required-sharepoint-files-issue) in the past. The trick has been that you need **all of those things**.

For some reason sometimes the even main code like sp.js isn't loaded or registered in a site. I have no idea why. So you need to register it.

But it might be and it might even be loaded already so you you need the `executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded()` in case it already is. But this won't load it if it isn't already being loaded.

So you then you need the  `executeFunc()` to load it if it isn't already on the way. But this won't do anything if it **is** already loaded.

```
//register the urls for the require files 
SP.SOD.registerSod('sp.js','_layouts/15/sp.js');

// if it isn't already loaded wait until it is loaded, and then do something
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    // Function calls or code in here.
}, "sp.js"); 

// load the file if it isn't already loaded, otherwise do nothing
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", null, null);
```

And, as in my linked example above, you may need to also register dependencies. Since we moved to this pattern we haven't had any timing or loading problems with our code that depends upon the SharePoint files.

Answer (score 0):

On the list custom form, the following works for me.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    //run the code only after sp.js has been loaded
      SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){

      GetContextuserRoles();

      YourFunctionTwo();    


      });

  });
```

Comment: the probleme is GetContextuserRoles() and YourFunctionTwo() are in seperate file js